# Change ExtJS Grid Height in Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, height

How can I point at the object of a ExtJS Grid and manually set the height (in pixels)?

For example, with this same:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {id:'company',header: 'Company', width: 160, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {header: 'Price', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: 'usMoney', dataIndex: 'price'},
        {header: 'Change', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: change, dataIndex: 'change'},
        {header: '% Change', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: pctChange, dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
        {header: 'Last Updated', width: 85, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'company',
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Array Grid',
    // config options for stateful behavior
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'grid'        
});
```

I would i be able to point at the "grid" object and then set the size of the grid?

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not perfectly sure if i did understand what you want. Do you want to set the grid heigth at initialisation of the grid or after rendering?

for setting the height at startup using php use:

```
var heigtht_set = <?php echo $grid_height ?>;

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
...
    height: heigtht_set ? heigtht_set : 350,
...       
});
```

you may also set the variable heigtht_set to any other available javascript variable;

if you want to setthe height to 600 after rendering of the grid you may use setHeight():

```
var heigtht_set = 600;
grid.setHeight(heigtht_set);
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Thariama answer's above, if you don't or can't keep a reference to the 'grid' variable you can give an ID to the component you are creating and use later in the code the `ExtJS::getCmp` method to get a reference back to the ExtJS Component you created using it's ID. Notice in this configuration the configuration property 'id' is set to 'myGrid'

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {id:'company',header: 'Company', width: 160, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {header: 'Price', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: 'usMoney', dataIndex: 'price'},
        {header: 'Change', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: change, dataIndex: 'change'},
        {header: '% Change', width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: pctChange, dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
        {header: 'Last Updated', width: 85, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'company',
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Array Grid',
    // config options for stateful behavior
    stateful: true,
    stateId: 'grid',
    id: 'myGrid'
});
```

After your grid is initiated open up firebug and the following code will set the height of the grid:

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid').setHeight(600);
```

Comment: +1 for Ext.getCmp('myGrid').setHeight(600); very useful tip always to set an id and use it.